# Migrate data from a table in an Oracle schema to another Oracle schema (with differences in columns etc)

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, data-migration, oracle19c

- We are extracting and rewriting some functionality from the current
  application into a microservice with its own Oracle schema.
- The new app has a different schema hence we will have to migrate the
  data (single table) from the earlier schema to this schema (single
  table)
- What that also means is that both schemas are/have different users with their own sets of wallets, editions, configurations, etc
- The data will also require some transformation i.e. it's not a one-to-one mapping. (e.g. date timestamps might change or some values would need to change etc)
- The amount of data is not much. (~1k to -2k rows)
- Oracle version is 19c.
- Both schemas reside in the same DB

**Possible solution and issue with it:** We are thinking of creating a simple Java application to do this i.e. read from the old table transform and write into another table. The problem is this would need downtime which we want to avoid.

 
**Questions:**

1. Is there some way in Oracle where we can keep the 2 schemas in
   sync (data transformed and synched)? I found something called
   Datapump however as I am not an Oracle admin I am not sure if it
   synchs the data in real-time or requires manual effort or other
   challenges that I might face using it.
2. What are some other strategies that we can use to avoid downtime and
   migrate the data as well?

Comment: Why do you think you need downtime? The source table is live and there is no problem selecting from while it's live. The target table doesn't exist so there's no downtime there. Do you need to keep running constant replication between the two tables or can you just do one migration and cutover?

Comment: What if the source table gets updated as soon the primary migration is done? Then a delta migration will have to done.

Comment: You need to specify you cutover plan. How long will the original table still be running after your data migration? Usually you freeze the source table, run the migration (which shoudl take seconds) then ensure everyone has cutover to the new table. This means you don't need to add all that complexity around incremental synchronisation

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say whether old and new schema reside in the same database or not.

If **YES**, then things are somewhat simpler: new user should

```
grant insert on that_table to old_user;
```

and old user would then just

```
insert into new_user.that_table
  (id, name, address, whatever)
  select id, user_name, user_address, whatever_else --> note different column names
  from old_users_table;

commit;
```

Once you commit, new user has all the data and *end users* - who have to access that table - can do it.

---

If **NO**, then things are a little bit more complicated because you'll have to create a **database link** (in any direction) and do the insert:

```
create database link dbl_old_to_new
  connect to new_user
  identified by its_password
  using 'new_database_alias';

insert into that_table@dbl_old_to_new
  (id, name, address, whatever)
  select id, user_name, user_address, whatever_else --> note different column names
  from old_users_table;

commit;
```

---

I guess that's the simplest way to do it. **Datapump** is more complex; you can use `REMAP_DATA` to handle different column names, but `SYS` (on both databases!, if there are two of them) should create a directory (Oracle object), grant privileges on it to users who will be using it ... not that it is *impossible* to move data that way, I just think that this is more complex.

---

As of a **simple Java application**: no idea, I don't use Java.

Comment: Yes both schemas are in the same PDB i.e same DB. (Updated the question with this info)

Comment: Can the SQL script handle transformations? The data might not have one-to-one mapping. Also, both the schemas can only be accessed via wallets, TNS file, etc would that be an impediment of some sort?

Comment: Transformation: I believe so, it is about query you'd write so that *source* gets into *target* as you want it to. As of *wallets*, sorry - I don't use that so I can't comment it.

Comment: Yes a SQL Script can definitely handle transformations. There are many data solutions that do many complex transformations in the database only. There is no need for any Java here. Even though this is the technology you are familiar with, it is not the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks Nick, yes hence thought of asking the question. Can you please list someone of them especially if any of them are open source one.

Comment: The solution I pose is that you write your tranasformations in Oracle SQL, made up of SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `materialized view` with fast refresh to automatically synchronize changes on commit in the source table. As long as MV is a table with some extra metadata/objects, you may add constraints, indexes etc on its base table. After the migration is complete - drop the materialized view and keep the target table.

Prepare input for showcase:

```
SQL> create table test_eas.old_table
  2  as
  3  select level as id, lpad(level, 3, '0') as val
  4  from dual
  5  connect by level < 4
  6  /

Table TEST_EAS.OLD_TABLE created.
```

Create MV log to allow fast refresh and grant permissions to the target user to access it:

```
SQL> create materialized view log
  2  on test_eas.old_table
  3  with rowid for fast refresh
  4  /

SQL> grant select on test_eas.old_table to test2;
SQL> grant select on test_eas.mlog$_old_table to test2;
SQL> grant on commit refresh on test_eas.mlog$_old_table to test2;
```

Create materialized view using transformation logic in the query. I use `with rowid` to replicate source rows without having primary key in the source table.

```
SQL> /*This operation should be performed at the target schema,
  2  but I'll use `create any ...` priveleges on the same source schema not to switch)*/

SQL> create materialized view test2.new_table
  2  refresh on commit fast with rowid
  3  as
  4  select
  5    src.*, src.id + 1 as new_col
  6  from test_eas.old_table src
  7  /
```

Check initial replication:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test2.new_table
  3  /

        ID VAL             NEW_COL
---------- ------------ ----------
         1 001                   2
         2 002                   3
         3 003                   4
```

Modify some rows in the source:

```
SQL> insert into test_eas.old_table(id, val)
  2  values (100, 'qw')
  3  /

SQL> update test_eas.old_table
  2  set val = 'zxc'
  3  where id = 1
  4  /
```

Changes are not visible in the target unless commited:

```
SQL> select * from test2.new_table
  2  /

        ID VAL             NEW_COL
---------- ------------ ----------
         1 001                   2
         2 002                   3
         3 003                   4
```

Persist changes and check the result:

```
SQL> commit
  2  /

SQL> select * from test2.new_table
  2  /

        ID VAL             NEW_COL
---------- ------------ ----------
         2 002                   3
         3 003                   4
         1 zxc                   2
       100 qw                  101
```

Detach the table from the materialized view:

```
SQL> drop materialized view test2.new_table
  2  preserve table
  3  /

Materialized view TEST2.NEW_TABLE dropped.

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2  from test2.new_table
  3  /

        ID VAL             NEW_COL
---------- ------------ ----------
         2 002                   3
         3 003                   4
         1 zxc                   2
       100 qw                  101
```

Comment: Why even use a materialized view for 2K rows? It's overkill

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid To keep tables in sync as requested. If this is a one time activity with no transition period then it is definitely an overkill

Comment: OK I see so an Oracle materialized view is not just a performance object, it literally creates a second table and you can simply disconnect the MV at a later time

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, it is a table with a saved query and other refresh metadata. You may allow consumers on both objects that are in sync (redirecting updates to the base table) while all sessions that referece old object are not gone. Then drop the view and a trigger to allow direct changes on the underlying table.

Comment: Thanks @astentx. This seems promising. I will try this out in the next few days and update here.

Comment: As already commented you need to consider your cutover plan. This is additional complexity that supports data synchronisation if required, but for a few thousand records you should plan to just migrate and cutover and not introduce addiitonal complexity around incermental sync

Comment: OK, I ll will explore cutover as well, thanks!